I am using websocket in Spring Boot, but the address is not correct
I was building a simple chat program using WebSockets in Spring.
I set up websocketconfig and sent the address to Google's simple websocket client, but the address is undefined.
package fitnessapp.fitnesspartner.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat-websocket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();;
    }
}


When I used setAllowedOrigins instead of setAllowedOriginPatterns, I confirmed that the cors error was working on the server. However, after changing it, only undefined appears in Google simple websocket and no request is sent to the server.
A request comes to the server like this:
2024-05-11T18:36:25.328+09:00 TRACE 24288 --- [0.1-8443-exec-9] o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHandlerMapping : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler @384f0e32 ] and 1 interceptors
2024-05-11T18:36:25.329+09:00 DEBUG 24288 --- [0.1-8443-exec-9] o.s.w.s.s.t.h.DefaultSockJsService : Processing transport request: GET https://172.18.240.1:8443/chat-websocket
It displays like this in the browser:
chat.html:15 WebSocket connection to 'wss://172.18.240.1:8443/chat-websocket' failed:
